# Чем отличается ethernet от serial?

Tags: serial, порт, ethernet

Подскажите, чем отличается ethernet от serial? В интернете только общими словами описано, а в книгах по разному.

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего (т.к. не указан контекст употребления терминов) serial - это [RS-232](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/RS-232).
[Ethernet](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ethernet) же - это сетевой интерфейс.

У них разное назначение: RS-232 применяется для связи с периферийными устройствами (например, модемом), а Ethernet - для подключения к локальным сетям.

Answer (score 0):

Порты RS-232, как правило, передают отдельные байты по мере их получения. Большинство Ethernet устройств, напротив, будут ожидать до тех пор, пока пакет не будет предоставлен полностью, перед началом передачи, и буду ждать получения и проверки целого пакета, преждче чем делать его доступным программному обеспечению. И хотя биты и байты могут быть отправлены последовательно, софт это мало волнует. Он просто знает, что через короткий прмежуток времени, после того как контроллеру был "скормлен" пакет и сказано его отправлять, другой контроллер сообщит, что пакет доступен, и разрешит программе его вычитать.

Последовательный порт гарантирует передачу байтов данных, которые предоставляет софт, в хронологической последовательности, и так же в обратную сторону. Все Ethernet системы гарантируют, что при отправке пакета с одной ноды на другую, расположение байтов, предоставленных получателю, будет соответствовать расположению байтов, предоставленных отправителем. Однако, нет общей спецификации, требующей, чтобы хронологический порядок, в котором данные передаются, имели какое-либо отношение к их расположению в пакете.

Answer (score 0):

В таких случаях, чтобы облегчить понимание и не мудрить терминологией, стоит проводить аналогии.

Аналогом Serial port (он же rs232, COM port) будет USB port, тогда как аналогом Ethernet будет WI-Fi. В данном случае я делаю акцент на основной функции двух понятий.